# from here to the hotel vs from the hotel to here

Tags: grammar, morphology

> It is two miles from here to the hotel.

> It is two miles from the hotel to here.

The first example is commonly seen with no problem, but the second one seems not right. CGEL says "here" is an adverb and can't be used as a noun.  As a result, we can say " come here" but can't say "come to here". If so, in the two examples, "from" and " to" are both prepositions; why is "from here" right but " to here" isn't right?

Comment: The second one is unidiomatic, not so much because of the grammar (there was a BBC TV drama called "From there to here") but because we usually express distances the other way round, or in different words. "They won't take long to come from the hotel, it's only two miles" for example.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Thanks. I also saw another sentence from OED- How far is it to your house from here?  So, for the first example, can I say " It is two miles to the hotel from here" instead ?

Comment: Yes, or "It is two miles from here to the hotel".

Comment: I don't think the second one is unidiomatic. It depends on what exactly you are describing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on "correct" in this case, but from an idiomatic standpoint you don't want to reference your starting point from somewhere other than your current location when your current location is one of the two mentioned locations.

Or, to use *to* in this context, you have to be going *to* somewhere, but *here* is where you already are. You can *come from here*, but you can't *come to here* as you're already *here*.

*Come here* would always be used speaking to another, so *here* from your perspective is a correct reference point for whoever you're speaking to.

Similarly, going back to the original sentence (@gotube's comment):

> I cannot come here since I'm always where I am, but if someone else is
> at the hotel and they're coming to where I am, then "...from the hotel
> to here" is grammatically and semantically correct.

As best as I know, not using *to* in front of *here* is "just one of those rules" in English. Like *there*, *home*, *up*, *down*, *upstairs*, and *downstairs*.

You could instead say:

> The hotel is two miles from here.

Comment: Thanks, I learn a lot.

Comment: @user421993 me too, in trying to look things up to verify what I *thought* I knew ;) Glad it's helpful!

Comment: I cannot come here since I'm always where I am, but if *someone else* is at the hotel and they're coming to where I am, then "...from the hotel to here" is grammatically and semantically correct.

Comment: @gotube I meant to have covered that with "Come here would always be used speaking to another, so here from your perspective is a correct reference point for whoever you're speaking to." However it is different, just also referencing another rather than yourself. Mind if I copy/paste your comment into the answer? (going to unless told not to) I'm not sure I can phrase it more clearly or almost definitely not as concisely :)

Comment: @TCooper please do!

Answer (score 2):

If there's a verb of motion (come, drive, walk, travel, etc) then it's followed by "here" rather than "to here". I've no idea how grammarians would formulate this rule.

Without such a verb, describing "the distance from X to here" does need the "to", and "It's 5 miles from the hotel to here" is correct; it's just much more usual to describe the inverse distance from here to the hotel. But where it's not a symmetric relationship, that's not possible: "It's downhill all the way from the hotel to here".

Comment: So, can I interpret the " rule"(if any) as , we say " It's two miles from here" or " It's two miles to (a specific place) " in common cases and " It's two miles from (a specific place) to here" in a specific case or situation.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these sentences are grammatical and do not read as "wrong" to me (a native speaker) — but you are right there is something unusual about the second sentence.

In fact, I would say that the second sentence is not so much *un*usual as it is *less* usual. That is, the first sentence works generally, no matter what the context of your conversation is, insofar as that context includes you being somewhere two miles away from a hotel known to both you and whoever you are talking to. This is usually how you'd talk about such a situation!

But, once in a while, there would be a time when the second sentence is even more useful than the first! It's the middle of the winter, your car is stuck in a snow drift, and you're on the phone with your colleague who drove separately to the after-conference party. You are trying to convince him/her to come pick you up, but he (or she) suggests that it's fine, you should just walk to the hotel. "The hotel is two miles from here! It's freezing and I don't even have a jacket on!" You bark incredulously into your smartphone.

All this to say the second sentence works fine in a specific case of emphasizing that you are *here*, and the hotel is two miles distant.